# Truffle test. Convert '0x0000000000000000' to zero. Assert it doesn't exist

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I am writing a truffle javascript test and I need to test if a key in a mapping was deleted. After deleting it, its values are equal to '0x0000000...' . How can I test in a truffle javascript test that that equals to zero?

```
  magicSmartContract.delete_card('33');
  deleted_card = await magicSmartContract.get_card('33');
  assert(deleted_card[0], 0);  // This
```

It is a js question I know, I am just wondering if there is an easy way to do this. deleted_card[0] is `'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var nullAddr = "0x0000...." // 40 x 0
assert.strictEqual(deleted_card, nullAddr, "card is not zero");
```

Hope it helps.